# Websphere, how deploy an ear keeping the administrator privilege for the application

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, wsadmin

I can successfully deploy MyApp to WebSphere 8.5 using certain jython script, but I can't start such application neither by admin console nor by jython commands due to

```
WASX7017E: exception information: ADMN0022E: Access is denied for the startApplication operation ... because of insuficient credentials.
```

I can see the server I am deploying to under "You can administer the following resources", but after I deployed MyApp, MyApp went into "You can monitor following resources". Basically, MyApp is deployed successfully to the server that I do have administration permission but the application itself is under the Monitor role. As far as I can see, since I am deploying an application to a server which I have administrator role, I should automatically have administrator permission for the application as well. Honestly, this is my first time deploying to WebSphere 8.5 and as far as I remember from WAS 7, there wasn't an issue like this. The real impact is: I can remove the application, I can deploy the application but I can't start the application neither in the exact same deployment script nor separately.

Should I add some parameter during deployment process in order to guarantee the application is hold under my admin role?

Would the "-installed.ear.destination" used during the AdminApp.install(...) be causing such issue? If so, what could be the expected path in order to allow me to start the application?

Comment: Can you 1) shorten the title once you've fixed the question and 2) fix the question. It is at the moment a wall of "stuff" which few are likely to take the time to read.

Comment: Looks like you may have `Configurator` role, not the `Administrator`. Try if you can restart the server, the application should be automatically started after you restart the server.

Comment: Gas, I restarted the server but the application didn't start. In fact, I stopped the server and the server automatically started by it self. Btw, the application keeps stopped. There something that is very strange to me and I spent whole day yesterday searching an reason for this: I am the administrator of myServer, myApp is under Application servers > myServer > Installed Applications so, shouldn't I be the administrator of all applications installed in myServer?

Comment: Enable the trace and paste the log contents. If it's IBM Products, for example in case of events, trace string is com.ibm.wbe.*=all and try to install sample application and see if it works